# Product of positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a finite set of positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices $\{A_i\}$, do we know that their product $\Pi_i A_i$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: The product of two positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ is always diagonalisable, but the product of three or more positive semidefinite matrices is not.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of three or more postitve semidefinite matrices is not always diagonalisable, as shown in the example
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&2}\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -1&2}I_2\cdots I_2=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}.
$$
However, the product of two postitve semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ is always diagonalisable. By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{P&0\\ 0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Y^\ast&Z},\ AB=\pmatrix{PX&PY\\ 0&0}
$$
where $P$ is positive definite. Since $B$ is positive semidefinite, the column space of $Y$ must lie inside the column space of $X$. That is, $Y=XW$ for some matrix $W$. Hence
$$
\pmatrix{I&W\\ 0&I}AB\pmatrix{I&-W\\ 0&I}
=\pmatrix{I&W\\ 0&I}\pmatrix{PX&PY\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{I&-W\\ 0&I}
=\pmatrix{PX&0\\ 0&0}.
$$
Since $PX$ is similar to the Hermitian matrix $P^{1/2}XP^{1/2} =P^{-1/2}(PX)P^{1/2}$, it is diagonalisable. Therefore $PX\oplus0$ and $AB$ are diagonalisable too.